# Is custom cell class model, view or controller?

Tags: swift, model-view-controller

I know this question may not be right one on this site but I was arguing my friend about it. I made custom `cell` `class` for custom `cell`. I said to my friend it is `View` but I can't say arguments to him. So can you guys say to me is it `model`, `View` or `Controller` if you should classify it?

I've classified them like this for now:

[image]

I am actually not so harsh on it to classify them since I am still learning but it would be good to know.

Comment: What does UITableViewCell inherit from? This may give you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cell is definitely a view.
It is not a model, because it doesn't stores the data, it is just present this data to user.
And it is not a controller, because cell itself doesn't containt any business logic (usually only setting up properties from input model or something like that)
So cell is a view, because it definitely has the role of view - presenting data, and that's all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was what I thought in my head but I was afraid to say it. Doesn't want to make myself idiot.

Comment: `And it is not a controller, because cell itself doesn't containt any business logic`. But the controller does __NOT__ contain business logic. The model does.

Comment: Cell is not a controller also because it doesn't "controll" anything, which is the main idea of a Controller. I mean controllers also may not contain business logic, because this logic may be moved in some service, but in MVC architecture Controller is "the main guy" who controls everyone around him)